# How to preserve emacs colors from regular terminal to gnu screen

Tags: macos, emacs, colors, terminal, gnu-screen

I'm using OSX snow leopard, for the record.

When I use emacs straight from terminal, I have a color set (e.g. for c/c++) that I'm very happy with---green on black, red comments, colored key words... etc etc.  Some of this is set in my 'terminal preferences', and some is in my ~/.emacs file (see below).  When I run emacs from screen, the basic color-scheme is the same (green on black), but the coloring is different (e.g. comment characters are red, but not the entire comments) -- and really annoying.

Any help would be appreciated!

In my '.emacs' file (this stops working in gnu-screen emacs):

```
(global-font-lock-mode t)
(custom-set-faces
 '(font-lock-comment-face
   ((((class color) (background light))
     :foreground "tomato")
    )))
```

In my '.screenrc' file:

```
shell -$SHELL            # colors still don't work without this
#term xterm-256color    # using this doesn't fix the colors (suggested on some forums)

altscreen on
startup_message off
```

I thought that the command 'shell -$SHELL' in my .screenrc file made the command prompt in screen the same as the default --- it **does** make my command line say 'computername:/DIR/ username$' instead of just 'bash-3.2$'

=================================================================

**Solution**:  Thanks to **Greg E.**

I needed to set my terminal emulator in screen to match that of my normal shell.  To do this, I added

```
export TERM='xterm-color'
```

to ~/.bash_profile

For some reason, 'term xterm-color' in the '~/.screenrc' file didn't work.

Comment: NOTE: On Mac OS X 10.7 Lion and later, using `xterm-color` is not recommended. It represents an older branch of xterm. In Lion, Terminal is compatible enough with modern xterm that you should use `xterm-256color` (the default) or a variation, e.g., `xterm-16color`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suspicion is that, while your terminal may be compiled with support for more than the standard 16 colors, your particular version of GNU screen may not be. I'm not very familiar with OSX, but on Linux I'd check whether the output of `tput colors` differs between a plain terminal and one running screen (I'd expect there to be some OSX equivalent if `tput` is not available). If it does, you may need to install (or manually compile) a different build of screen that includes support for additional colors (normally, 256 is the maximum, but 88 is also common, while 16 is the default minimum).

Edit: Ultimately, the correct solution proved to be manually setting the `$TERM` environment variable (see comments below).

Comment: Interesting idea; I tried 'tput colors' (which does work), and it responded '8' in both regular terminal and in screen.... :/

Comment: @zhermes, what's the current value of `$TERM` and what terminal emulator are you using? An output of 8 means your terminal, as it's currently configured, doesn't have support for anything other than the 8 base ANSI colors (and their bright/bold counterparts, making a total of 16). Hence, a color like `"tomato"` would likely get intelligently resolved down to `"red"`. Consider installing `xterm` with 256-color support, if possible. Also, [this page](http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/) might be helpful. You could try setting different `$TERM` values and see if the `tput colors` output changes.

Comment: Interesting... my doubt about that is that they both say '8', while the only problem is in one of them.  So maybe there are different algorithms for converting down 'tomato' ?

'echo $TERM' yields "xterm-color", and when I do the same in screen it just says 'screen'... Here's where I show my dumb, I thought I was *using* terminal, not an emulator.  ?

Comment: @zhermes, the distinction between "terminal" and "terminal emulator" is a pedantic and obscure bit of nomenclature; see [the relevant Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) if you're really curious. Anyway, my suggestion to resolve the coloring inconsistency is to add the line `term xterm-color` to your `~/.screenrc`. If that fails for some reason, you could also try adding something like the following to your bash configuration files (i.e., `~/.bashrc`, and one of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, or `/etc/profile`): `export TERM='xterm-color'`.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  It didn't work in .screenrc, but it did in .bash_profile (I didn't have a '.bashrc' in my ~)

Comment: @zhermes, no problem. Glad to have helped. BTW, `~/.bashrc` is the file that's sourced by bash when you run it as an interactive/non-login shell. The hyphen in the `shell -$SHELL` line your `~/.screenrc` instructs screen to execute your default shell in login mode, so, in this instance, adding the line to `~/.bashrc` is unnecessary. That said, you might want to create that file anyway, just to ensure that your `$TERM` variable is properly configured if you ever end up running your shell in interactive mode.

Comment: When i do this, it fixes colours, but some of my keyboard keys (the 'end' key for instance) stop functioning within emacs. `^e` (`c-e`, or control-e) still works as normal, though. Not especially surprising, since I know a lot of physical TTY's didn't include home/end dedicated keys (and neither do macs, for that matter, unless using certain keyboards), but still bothersome. Encountered the issue after a debian update patched mate-terminal to use 256 colours.