# How can I fix shell colours in Emacs?

Tags: shell, emacs

I have a wierd error, I can't seem to get pretty ls colours when using the emacs basic shell. While googling I tried sourcing my bashrc which defines the color vector (which works for my other external shells), I've tried adding

```
(autoload 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on "ansi-color" nil t)
```

to my .emacs, neither of which helped.

I then spotted some wierd behaviour. When I start a shell, exit the process and then start another shell in the same buffer, the hostname colour from the previsous session changes.

[image]
I have no idea what to try from here! Any ideas?

I'm running GNU Emacs for OSX version 24.3.50.1

Comment: Can you get ls to show colours in a normal shell (I suspect the issue is that OSX uses BSD ls which does not show colours whilst Linux uses GNU's ls)

Comment: Sadly I do get colors in my normal terminal. I normally alias ls to have -GFh (not in example posted) arguments, the -F shows up but no colors :/

Comment: What happens if you use `ansi-term` or `term` instead of `shell`?

Comment: And what is the value of the variable `ansi-color-names-vector`? You can check this using the following key sequence `C-h v ansi-color-names-vector`

Comment: Both ansi and term have coloured outputs, but I'm curious as to why shell is resisting my efforts to make it pretty. ansi-color-names-vector's value is ["black" "red" "green" "yellow" "blue" "magenta" "cyan" "white"]

Answer (score 1):

With help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148321/how-to-preserve-emacs-colors-from-regular-terminal-to-gnu-screen), I was able to get it working by simply explicitly exporting `TERM=xterm-256color` in `~/.emacs.d/init_bash.sh`.  Haven't played around with it much yet, but it seems to do the thing now.  Maybe it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `ls --color=always`; ls may not recognize that colors are available, and this will tell it to use them anyway. If that works, then an easy way to use that all the time is to define an alias: `alias ls='ls --color=always` (note that aliases are a Bash feature, not an Emacs feature). It's likely that you already have an alias or two defined in your Bash profile, so it may just be a matter of editing that one to make the change permanent.

Comment: As Mark said, OSX uses BSD, so ls doesn't accept --color=always, it does accept -G which enables color, but runnning ls -G in emacs shell doesn't give colors.

Comment: Good catch, I ignored that detail.